# How to access Outlook Contact Data with PHP

Tags: php, outlook

I want to access MS Outlook application using PHP. I have a Outlook Contact Group Name. I need to get the owner of the Contact Group.

I looked for help on Google but i found some random stuff. Nothing useful.

Please help me with the basic how can i  connect php to outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the Outlook Object Model or interact with a running instance of the Outlook UI from a web application.  If you want access to Outlook *data*, then it depends on the account you want to access.  The data for POP accounts are stored locally in .pst files, which you also cannot access from the web app.  But if the Outlook data is in Exchange, use Exchange Web Services in your web app to access the data.